# The error message of php put file content function

Tags: php

I am using `file_put_contents`. However, it returns false. How can I get the description 
of the error ? I cannot figure out why this is not working. Here is my code:

```
$fpc1=file_put_contents("c\\payment". "\\file1.txt", "$headercolumn\n$data");
$fpc2=file_put_contents("c\\payment". "\\file2.txt", "$headercolumn\n$data");
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be `c:`?

Comment: Why don't you use E_ALL for error reporting.?

Comment: By typing php get last error on google ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: @Virus721 English please -)

Comment: First of all, I’d advise against using the \ as directory separator (the masking makes it ugly and error-prone) – PHP under Windows can handle `/` just as well. And then, if you have no specific reason to use an absolute path, use a relative one.

Comment: You may use also the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR Constant to separate directories. Makes it more flexible between different OS's

Comment: I didn't notice but it doesn't require so much IQ to replace fr by en in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

If error reporting is on, then an error should appear. Try to turn it on to see what's going on.

Also, given the path of the file, I suspect you to have mis-typed the drive letter. (If it's a drive letter, then it's C:\ and not c)

I recommend you to check the path, then check the permissions for that file (chmod 777 or 666 on linux, writable in windows)

Also, why are you using concatenation with two constant strings?

Comment: Thanks Atrakeur. I am just use strings for testing and I forget to change it.